# How to stop the rest of code in current method from executing in Java?

Tags: java

I have 4 textboxes, 2 of them being password boxes (for the user to confirm their password).

Here's my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String username = usernameField.getText();
    String emailAddress = emailField.getText();
    String password1 = passwordField1.getText();
    String password2 = passwordField2.getText();
    if (password1 != password2) {
        [code here]
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that if the passwords aren't equal it stops the rest of the code in that method from executing?

Comment: you can use a if, a loop, a return or throw an exception.

Comment: This was incorrectly closed...

Comment: just `if (test) { return; }`

Comment: @Makoto He didn't ask anything about how to compare strings. He asked how to stop further code execution of the method if a certain condition was met.

Comment: Very well.  I'll withdraw my close vote.

Comment: "The rest of the method" refers to the block of the `if` statement. Pretty sure it was correctly closed.

Comment: @ChrisMartin:  I'm comfortable with a reopen on this one since it's not a carte-blanche duplicate.  Yes, the duplicate is related, but it's not asking the exact same question with a slightly different flavor.

Comment: @JustinG You can take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a significant problem *before* you can do this:  you have to compare strings correctly.  Then, you can decide what to do if they're false.  Ultimately, using `return` in a `void` method is acceptable if you only want to return.

```
if (!password1.equals(password2)) {
    // [code here]
}
```

However, the better approach would be to do a simple blanket check, and avoid the [early return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/1079354) - if the passwords *are* valid, then do operations in the scope of that block.  The fall-through case would exit the method early.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String username = usernameField.getText();
    String emailAddress = emailField.getText();
    String password1 = passwordField1.getText();
    String password2 = passwordField2.getText();
    if (password1.equals(password2)) {
        // code on success here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was able to figure it out. Sorry for posting this "duplicate" or whatnot, it seems I had more than 1 issue. EDIT: Regarding the way you suggested doing it, I'd have to include a bunch of nested if statements due to the fact that I also want to check username length, password length, etc...

Comment: @JustinG:  I admit I acted a bit in haste when closing it, but generally when one sees two strings being compared with `==`, it's understandable.   Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

**Never** compare strings with boolean operators - Bad practice!

To solve your question just do this:

```
if (!password1.equals(password2)) {
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to stop the rest of code in current method from executing in Java?

I would say there are 2 ways:

1. Let the program flow naturally to the end of the method:

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(password1.equals(password2)){
           //Do all the things if password is correct
       }            
   } //<-- If password is incorrect, point of execution will come to here
   ```
2. To exit a method before you reach the end of the method, you can use `return`:

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(!password1.equals(password2)){
           return;
       }
       else{
           //Do all the things if password is correct
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `return` statement:

```
return;
```

Comment: Does this fix the comparison?

Comment: And this is why there's a downvote:  you failed to address the actual problem.  Yes, returning is correct, but it's not going to work out for them if *all* they do is this.

Comment: @cricket_007:  your edit leaves a bad taste in my mouth, since it's not the answer that was originally given.

Comment: @Makoto, can we chat?

Comment: I don't have the luxury of time right now; I've just taken a brief break, but if you put a question in a chatroom that I can get to, I will answer it when I have a spare moment.